# How to get last 10 inserted data in aws Dynamo DB?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I know this is repeated question , but i can't find the solution for my case.
My dynamo db table data is:

```
{

"DATE": "01-08-2017",

"col1": "1.21",

"col2": "342.39",

"col3": "0.04",

"col4": "9.09",

"col5": "5.49",

"col6": "17.61"

}
```

Date column is partion key , my table don't have sort key.
daily lambda function will insert data like above row.
Now my table has more than 150 records, I want to get last 10 records using php dynamoDB API.
I tried *Query* and *Scan* method, please anyone help . Give some sample code.

Comment: You want to get last inserted 10 records?

Comment: Yes, But Dynamodb records are not in order in table.

Comment: Why do you not use a sort key?

Comment: Introduce a time stamp or check this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461897/dynamodb-get-earliest-inserted-distinct-values-from-a-table/34463999#34463999

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible given your existing table schema. The only way you can extract sorted data in DynamoDB is if you use a range key.

You would need to create a range key that increments each time you add an item. Then when you do a query or scan you could limit the results to 10 items, the data will always be sorted within the partition by the range key.

Answer (score 0):

Use a sort key that is the time in milliseconds since 1970 (unix epoch time). Then give each item you add this as the sort key when you add it through lambda but that figure as a negative number. i.e. as `-1574827364892` 
Just subtract the number from 0 before you add it in Lambda.
This will add results to the end of your table rather than the front. 
Then scan the table with a limit of 5 results and you will get the latest 5.
It's a cheap hack but hey.